# Durable function Timeout

Tags: azure-durable-functions, timeoutexception, long-running-processes

I'm Using Azure Durable Functions .Net Core.

```
[FunctionName("Calculate")]
public async Task RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal1, null);
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal2, null);
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal3, null);
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal4, null);
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal5, null);   
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal6, null);
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal7, null);
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal8, null);
    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>(FuncConstants.Cal9, null);
}

[FunctionName("Starter_Calculation")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Calculate", null);
    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```

Here, each function takes more than 5-6 hours to perform some logical calculations (arithmetic operations) as they deal with more than 27-30 million database records.

I'm getting the error for the first function itself as  `"Timeout value of 00:30:00 was exceeded by function`. In Azure, I'm using `Premium App Service Plan`, so I can set `AlwaysOn`.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is Azure Function the best fit for such a scenario/long-running operations?
2. If yes, is there any way I can test it locally without a time-out error?

Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a Premium or Dedicated (App Service) plan, the default timeout for a function is 30 minutes - which is what you're hitting.

You can extend it by configuring `functionTimeout` in host.json.

For either of those plans, there is technically no maximum timeout. Though for Premium, execution is only guaranteed for 60 minutes.

See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

There are 2 main strategies for avoiding timeouts with durable functions:

1. increase the timeout via host.json
2. break the work down into smaller units, and have more activity function calls

The 2nd strategy is valuable - smaller unit of work gives you better recovery/resume experience in event of transient failures. Plus, you can parallelize activity function calls to reduce overall processing time.

To run multiple activity functions in parallel, you can `await Task.WhenAll` multiple activity calls - check out the example in the Fan Out-Fan In pattern in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp#e2_backupsitecontent-orchestrator-function

It's not clear from your example, whether your activity functions need to wait for the previous one to complete (i.e. have to chain together serially), or whether they are completely independent and therefore can be done in parallel. But, the power of Durable Functions is that support various patterns and take care of a lot of underlying coordination for you.

Comment: I got the first point. Need some more inputs on `parallelize activity function calls to reduce overall processing time.`

Comment: @UnknownCoder - added a pointer on that to my answer

Comment: Basically, each function needs to wait for the previous one to complete.

Comment: Ok, in that case, to achieve 2) - you'd need to e.g. convert Cal1 activity function to an orchestrator function (which you can call as a sub-orchestration). That could then internally break the workload down into smaller chunks and parallelize over multiple Activity function calls.

Premise is still the same if you want to either reduce individual Activity function durations and/or reduce overall throughput.

Comment: Typo in my above comment... "...and/or INCREASE overall throughput" :D

Comment: If I get it correctly, the time limit of one activity function can be bypassed by splitting it into several smaller ones. Let's say the limit is 60 minutes. So, each smaller function still has its own 60 minutes, right? And as far as I experience, I think the orchestrator does not really stay idle while `await`. Because they finish executing and then resume when one of smaller units completes. This action also 'renew' the time limit of the parent orchestrator, right? Many thanks